# Telegram API create public channel

Tags: api, telegram, mtproto

How I can create public channels with Telegram API? I've tried https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto, and it worked, but it creates only a private channel.

Answer (score 5):

To create a public supergroup, you first must create it using [channels.createChannel](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/channels_createChannel.html) and then set a username using [channels.updateUsername](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/channels_updateUsername.html)